# HTML & CSS - Safari web and mobile wont work

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari, css-animations

Hello I have some animation on avatar that does not work on Safari.
Animation is about two lines that goes around avatar. I added `@-webkit-keyframes` but still nothing has changed. Code is here:

**(First class that calls keyframe)**

```
.bp-user {

    content: '';
    animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;
}
```

**(keyframe that work on chrome but not in safari)**

```
@-webkit-keyframes clipMe {

    0%, 100% {clip: rect(0px, 160px, 0px, 0px);}
    25% {clip: rect(0px, 0px, 160px, 0px);}
    50% {clip: rect(160px, 160px, 160px, 0px);}
    75% {clip: rect(0px, 160px, 160px, 160px);}
    100% {clip: rect(0px, 160px, 0px, 0px);}
}
```

Comment: your first line in `@-webkit-keyframes clipMe` has both `0%, 100% {...}` .. is that right ? Also just to confirm, is your Safari version 4 ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa first line is right and it works on other browsers except on Safari. My Safari version is 5.1.7, and on mobile dont know exactly the version but its iPhone 6 so I think I have close to latest version. Also I found that safari need keyframes to go from 0%  and must contain 100% I put that but still nothing

Comment: Also in safari short hand notations give a problem so instead of `-webkit-animation: clipMe 8s linear infinite;` try `-webkit-animation-name: clipMe;
-webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;`. Can you confirm

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I tried still nothing on Safari web and Safari mobile its not moving its just fixed and it look like border

Comment: `clip`  is deprecated/obsolete - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip USe `clip-path` instead.

Comment: @Paulie_D if you mean this:
@-webkit-keyframes clipMe {
    0%, 100% {
    clip-path: rect(0px, 160px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  25% {
    clip-path: rect(0px, 0px, 160px, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    clip-path: rect(160px, 160px, 160px, 0px);
  }
  75% {
    clip-path: rect(0px, 160px, 160px, 160px);
  }
     100% {
    clip-path: rect(0px, 160px, 0px, 0px); 
  }

}
I already tried that with clip-path